# LinqDataSource - how do I select rows based on the current UserId?

Tags: gridview, guid, where-clause, linqdatasource, userid

I have a Grid View control that displays data based on what is returned by the LinqDataSource.  The LinqDataSource selects data depending on the date chosen in a date control (used in the where clause), but I also need the where clause to be based on the current userID which is a GUID.

How can I get the LinqDataSource to obtain the Current User ID and use it in the where clause?  My code currently looks like something like this (in the .aspx page)

```
Where=UserID == GUID?(@UserID)

<asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="UserId" />
```

I hope that's enough information - please let me know if you need more! :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, I stopped using the smart tag and ended up writing the query in the _Selecting event of the LinqDataSource.  That seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I had the same problem:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ... Where="UserID == Convert.ToInt32(@UserID)">
  <WhereParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="UserID" ControlID="hdnUserID"
      Type="Int32" PropertyName="Value" />
  </WhereParameters>
</asp:LinqDataSource>

<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnUserID" Visible="false" />
```

Then I set the `Value` attribute of `hdnUserID` from code-behind. It's a hack, but works.